# ipsec tunnel disconnects for 10 minutes every x hours, where x varies depending on the lifetime - cisco asa

Tags: cisco, tunnel, ipsec

has anyone faced an issue, where the ipsec tunnel disconnects for 10 minutes every x hours, where x varies depending on the lifetime, specifically when dealing with a cisco asa?

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending ICMP Pings across the VPN Tunnel once the Lifetime expires, to see if the VPN tunnel comes back up? or no matter what traffic you send across the tunnel the VPN still does not come up until after the 10mins?

Make sure the Lifetime is configure the same on both sides.

Comment: yes i have a ping on the tunnel running always (still the tunnel disconnects). Also we tried having identical lifetimes on both ends however still the problem persists.